# How to change the color of html datalist

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can change the color of the datalist (black box appearing in the image)

[image: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist]

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

EDIT: you might be seeing it as white, it takes the default color of system

Answer (score 1):

Datalist has very few to no possibilities when it comes to design. There may be vendor specific styling, but I would not advice using them in production environments.

The best workaround is to repaint the whole datalist with JavaScript like `awsomplete` does it. -> https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/

Comment: Thanks for your answer , this is a great alternative, but adds a over head of using external js,  I just wanted to know , if someone have done something to over come this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style these elements like `select` and `datalist` it has very little flexibility in styling.

Browsers define their own styles to the *elements* I mentioned above.

[Try to read this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions)